# Is it possible to use a proxy with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know if I can use a proxy with a javascript ajax call, either with jQuery or standard javascript.

Maybe something like this:

```
var ajax = new Ajax({
    proxy:'123.123.123.1:8080',
    proxyUsername:'myUsername',
    proxyPassword:'myPassword',
    ...etc
});
```

The purpose is to download a file from a third party while faking the users IP address.

Answer (score 4):

No. Browsers will not let you set a different proxy server for XHR requests.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with actionscript instead.